# How to merge multiple files in R in a very specific format?

Tags: r, merge

I have 5 csv files which have data like this:

> File 1:

```
 - rsid  chr pos a1 a0 beta  se   pvalue nsample 
 - rs1234 1  123 A  C  0.985 0.12 1e-5   1276
 - rs4567 2  234 T  G  0.276 0.34 1e-2   3847
 - rs8910 3  345 C  T  0.847 0.29 2e-6   3949
```

File 2:

```
- rsid   chr pos a1 a0 beta   se   pvalue nsample
- rs1234 1   123 A  C  0.598  0.93 1e-3   3949
- rs8910 3   345 C  T  0.3039 0.29 1e-3   0392
```

File3:

```
- rsid   chr pos a1 a0 beta  se   pvalue nsample
- rs1234 1   123 A  C  3.094 1.29 1e-2   0303
- rs4567 2   234 T  G  2.101 2.09 1e-2   9922
- rs8910 3   345 C  T  0.229 1.09 2e-3   9329
```

Similarly files 4 and 5.

I want them merged in this way: (The headers should be removed)

> 

```
- rs1234 1 123 A C
- 0.985 0.12 1e-5 1276             (from file 1)
- 0.598 0.93 1e-3 3949             (from file 2)
- 3.094 1.29 1e-2 0303             (from file 3)
- rs4567 2 234 T G
- 0.276 0.34 1e-2 3847            (from file 1)
- 0 0 0 0 0                       (from file 2)
- 2.101 2.09 1e-2 9922            (from file 3)
- rs8910 3 345 C T
- 0.847 0.29 2e-6 3949             (from file 1)
- 0.3039 0.29 1e-3 0392            (from file 2)
- 0.229 1.09 2e-3 9329             (from file 3)
```

For every rsid, the first five columns are the same in every file (i.e rsid, chr, pos, a1, a0). They become the first line. The rest of the columns have different details. They come one below another in the same order from file1, file2 and file3. If a particular rsid is not found in any file, then there should be zeros (0,0,0,0,0).

The word in brackets (from file1, from file2 and from file3) are for understanding. They need not be included in the merged file.

Comment: What you proposed will have different column numbers. For example, `rs1234 1 123 A C` has five columns, while `0.985 0.12 1e-5 1276` has four columns. So it does not make sense to create a combined data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different column names are bit strange but still can work around to get it.

```r
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread('rsid chr pos a1 a0 beta se pvalue nsample
rs1234 1 123 A C 3.094 1.29 1e-2 0303
rs4567 2 234 T G 2.101 2.09 1e-2 9922
rs8910 3 345 C T 0.229 1.09 2e-3 9329')
dt2 <- fread('rsid chr pos a1 a0 beta se pvalue nsample
rs1234 1 123 A C 0.598 0.93 1e-3 3949
rs8910 3 345 C T 0.3039 0.29 1e-3 0392')
dt3 <- fread('rsid chr pos a1 a0 beta se pvalue nsample
rs1234 1 123 A C 3.094 1.29 1e-2 0303
rs4567 2 234 T G 2.101 2.09 1e-2 9922
rs8910 3 345 C T 0.229 1.09 2e-3 9329')

dt1[,id:=1]
dt2[,id:=2]
dt3[,id:=3]

dt <- rbindlist(list(dt1,dt2,dt3))

RSID <- unique(dt$rsid)
ID <- unique(dt$id)

dtt <- dt[CJ(RSID,ID),on=.(rsid=RSID,id=ID)]
dtt[is.na(dtt)] <- 0

names(dtt) <- c("rsid", "chr", "pos", "a1", "a0", "rsid", "chr", "pos", "a1","id") # work around to fix names issue, which is onlu suitable for OP's question


extract_rsid <- function(x){
  rbindlist(list(dtt[rsid==x,.SD[1,1:5]],
                 dtt[rsid==x,6:9]),fill = TRUE)
}


l <- lapply(RSID,extract_rsid)


rbindlist(l)
#>       rsid  chr     pos   a1   a0
#>  1: rs1234 1.00 123.000    A    C
#>  2:  3.094 1.29   0.010  303 <NA>
#>  3:  0.598 0.93   0.001 3949 <NA>
#>  4:  3.094 1.29   0.010  303 <NA>
#>  5: rs4567 2.00 234.000    T    G
#>  6:  2.101 2.09   0.010 9922 <NA>
#>  7:      0 0.00   0.000    0 <NA>
#>  8:  2.101 2.09   0.010 9922 <NA>
#>  9: rs8910 3.00 345.000    C    T
#> 10:  0.229 1.09   0.002 9329 <NA>
#> 11: 0.3039 0.29   0.001  392 <NA>
#> 12:  0.229 1.09   0.002 9329 <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much @Frank Zhang! Worked beautifully :).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back, I was trying to fit the codes into my data :)